# Detecting if the Compact Framewok is installed on mobile device

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile, embedded

Ive written an application using the .net compact framework. One of the requirements is that a check is run before app runs to see if the compact framework is installed. If not I should prompt this to them and redirect them to cf download location.

What would be the best most common approach to doing this. Obviously my .net wont run in the first place if .net cf is not installed, do i need to write this in eVc++?

Much appreciate your thoughts on the
Tony

Comment: Hey, i saw the link which you have mentioned. its fine..
but i try downloading the sample app link mentioned there.
it doesn't have any .sln file only...
i am confused how to call those DLL's and functions...
can u provide some samples..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446531.aspx) is an MSDN article about creating an MSI Package that detects and updates the .NET Compact Framework, if this is required. It is pretty old, but the principles still apply. You need to write a dll that will run in the phone. You first search for compact framework's dll files and then you can get the version from a registry key. You can also detect the device type and install the appropriate compact framework cab files.

If you want to do it with a cab file, the process is still the same. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) on how you can run a set-up dll from a cab file.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [Mobile Packager](http://www.mobilepackager.com). We have used it to bundle multiple CAB deployment including .NET compact framework and only install it if it is not already installed.